# How to prove continuity so I can apply intermediate value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have to prove that there exists an $x\in [0,1]$ so that
$\sqrt{x+e^{-x}}=2x$

The new concept introduced in my course is continuity. I understand what it is theoretically, but I'm unclear on how to prove it. What I would like to do here, is show that $\sqrt{x+e^{-x}}=2x$ is continuous. Then I would pick two values in the interval, say $0.1$ and $0.9$ and show that they are geater than and lesser than $2x$ respectively.

Using the intermediate value theorem it would follow that a value for $x$ has to exists where $f(x)=2x$, right?

This all hinges on proving continuity and the explanation in my course has left me clueless. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What is the definition of continuity you were given?

Comment: Continuity can be applied only on functions not equations

Comment: @Sir Jective
They define it through convergence. I don't really understand what they try to say in my native language, so I'm not really confident enough to translate it to English. Sorry.

Comment: Are the requiring that you specifically use their definition?

Comment: @Sir Jective
I don't think so. I feel that if I can understand what needs to be shown and why it is a proof of continuity, I can finally understand the definition as well.

Comment: Then use the epsilon delta definition of continuity.

Comment: @Sir Jective
I have looked into that actually, but again I don't understand how to apply it to my problem or how it proves continuity.

Comment: It is the definition of continuity, so if you can show that the function meets that definition then is is continuous.

Comment: Try reading the first link in this Google search and then go back to the problem https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&ei=LsdiVqSXH-HljgTc8YSgCg&q=invariant+subspace&oq=invariant+&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.1.1.0l5.1393.3113.0.4408.11.11.0.5.5.0.198.1580.0j11.11.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-hp..0.11.976.3.Poo6QDVGBVA#q=examples+of+delta+epsilon+continuity

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$f(x):=\sqrt{x+e^{-x}}-2x\qquad(0\leq x\leq1)\ .$$
Since $f$ is "composed" (using $+$, $\circ$, etc.) from functions already established as continuous this $f$ is automatically continuous. Now
$$f(0)=1>0,\qquad f(1)=\sqrt{1+{1\over e}}-2<0\ ,$$
from which we can conclude that there is a $\xi\in\ ]0,1[\ $ with $f(\xi)=0$.

Comment: So I should write that because f is composed of e function, identity function and square root, which are all continuous, f is continuous? This makes sense, as we have that rule in our course. It also solves my problem. So thanks, however it doesn't bring me any closer to understanding how to prove continuity in general.